# Https request in Node.js

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I'm using the request library in Node.js to do a https request to get data from another service. This is called asynchronously, right? So my code keeps running before all of the data is there, correct?

My problem is that the data is needed right afterwards to calculate some things. My code throws an error during that calculation because the data from the service is undefined...
Could it be possible that the data is just not there yet? And if so, what do you do against that?

Here is a copy of the request:

```
const request = require('request');

request(someUrl, {"Accept": "application/json"}, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err)
        handleError(err);
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    return body;
});
```

Comment: When you say "the data is needed right afterwards to calculate some things" are you refering to a) the place in the code after request(...) is called or b) inside the callback function? Since you are using a callback function b) is the only place where result (i.e. body) is available - the return value of the callback function is discarded.

Comment: a)... its a function thats called and it should return the value... any way to put it in a function when I dont want to mess up my code and call that big code everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of situation is pretty common in react/angular/vue kinda web apps, sometimes you need the data right away. But it is not available then, after a Rest call or something it becomes available.

So, the simplest solution?
**Just add a check**, for example:

```
const calculate = (someVal)=>{
    if(!someVal) return ;
    //otherwise do the calculation
}
```

There are plenty of other ways, by mostly making the calculation async. For your function, you can do this

```
const promOp = function(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(someUrl, {"Accept": "application/json"}, (err, res, body) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            body = JSON.parse(body);
            resolve(body);
        });
    }
}
//then
promOp()
.then((body)=>{
    //calculate here
})

//or can use the `Async/Await` syntax instead of then
const op = async () => {
    const body = await promOp;
    //calculate here
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Two questions... why are you asinging the functions to constants? Why dont you just write them as normal functions? And why are you using arrow functions everywhere except at the prompOp constant function?

Comment: 1) both function syntaxes are basically interchangeable if you don't want hoisting. Means, when you create function expressions (like I did) the function is accessible only after the variable is declared. But in case of normal function even if you create the function at the bottom of the script it will be available at the top.

Comment: 2) No particular reason. you can use arrow function there as well. But as there were no scopes and such and fat arrow functions don't have it's own `this` context I wanted to maybe provide a scope of some sort which is not global. I did it subconsciously no particular reason. :) sorry for the weird answer